# Please help me with this sturcutre, designed to

Tags: sentence-construction

Please help me to understand out the structure of the following sentence:

> if appropriate, you should consider formulating national and regional
>   action plans, incorporating timetables, targets and provisions for
>   funding, designed to enhance enforcement of CITES, achieve compliance
>   with its provisions, and support wildlife-law enforcement agencies.

(https://stag.cites.org/sites/default/files/document/E-Res-11-03-R17A.pdf )

Here, I don't understand what "designed to enhance..." is.
Is this modifying something before the phrase?
Or is it acting like an adverb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sentence is confusingly written and badly punctuated. I think that it makes the most sense to consider "designed to enhance..." as a participial clause that modifies *plans*. I've tried to explicate the meaning by inserting explanatory words in **bold** that don't belong to the original.

> if appropriate, you should consider formulating **[the following two kinds of plans namely]**
>
> **1.** national **[action plans]** and
>       **2.** regional action plans,
>
> **[which plans should be]** incorporating **[the following three things, namely]**
>
> **1.** timetables,
>       **2.** targets **[,]** and
>       **3.** provisions for funding,
>
> **[and which plans should be]** designed **[to do the following three things, namely]**
>
> **1.** to enhance enforcement of CITES,
>       **2.** **[to]** achieve compliance with its provisions, and
>       **3.** **[to]** support wildlife-law enforcement agencies.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a poorly worded sentence, imho.

The “incorporating timetables, targets and provisions for funding” describes the expected contents of the action plans, and would be clearer if it were a separate sentence.

The “designed to...” part then describes the purpose or goals of the action plans.

> if appropriate, you should consider formulating national and regional action plans designed to enhance enforcement of CITES, achieve compliance with its provisions, and support wildlife-law enforcement agencies.
>
> Any action plans should incorporate timetables, targets and provisions for funding